# VBA Null Date Argument

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use a VBA UDF in access in an update query, but its not working. Here is my function:

```
Function final_forecast(status As String, _
    Optional LDP As String, _
    Optional fgpo_mode As String, _
    Optional fgpo_start As Date, _
    Optional fgpo_piw As Date, _
    Optional asn_mode As String, _
    Optional asn_piw As Date, _
    Optional maker As Double, _
    Optional origin As Double, _
    Optional water As Double, _
    Optional pod As Double, _
    Optional transit As Double, _
    Optional manual_piw As Date = 0, _
    Optional delivery As Date = 0) As Date
    
    Dim this_week, in_transit_piw, at_factory_piw, semi_final_piw, final_piw As Date
    
    this_week = Date - Weekday(Date, 1) + 7
    
    If status = "In Transit" Then
        If Not delivery = 0 Then
            in_transit_piw = delivery
        ElseIf Not manual_piw = 0 Then
            in_transit_piw = manual_piw
        ElseIf asn_mode = "A" Then
            in_transit_piw = asn_piw
        Else:
            in_transit_piw = DateAdd("d", nz(water, 0), asn_piw)
        End If
    ElseIf status = "At Factory" Then
        If fgpo_mode = "A" Then
            at_factory_piw = fgpo_piw
        ElseIf LDP = "LDP" Then
            at_factory_piw = DateAdd("d", nz(maker, 0) + nz(origin, 0) + nz(water, 0), fgpo_start)
        Else:
            at_factory_piw = DateAdd("d", nz(maker, 0) + nz(origin, 0) + nz(water, 0), fgpo_piw)
        End If
    End If
    
    If in_transit_piw < this_week Then
        semi_final_piw = this_week
    ElseIf fgpo_mode = "A" Then
        semi_final_piw = fgpo_piw
    ElseIf at_factory_piw < DateAdd("d", 21 + nz(water, 0), Date) Then
        If LDP = "LDP" Then
            semi_final_piw = this_week
        Else:
            semi_final_piw = DateAdd("d", 28 + nz(maker, 0) + nz(origin, 0) + nz(water, 0), Date)
        End If
    Else: semi_final_piw = at_factory_piw
    End If
    
    If semi_final_piw < this_week Then
        final_piw = this_week
    Else:
        final_piw = semi_final_piw
    End If
    
    final_forecast = final_piw
    
    
End Function
```

Here is a sample row that is throwing a "Compile Error: Expected Expression".

```
a = final_forecast("In Transit",,"B",#6/23/21#,#9/20/21#,"B",#8/11/21#,0,0,27,0,0,,)
debug.Print a
```

The last 2 arguments are empty date fields in my table. I have searched high and low for an answer. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

The update query looks like this:

```
UPDATE new_in_dc 
SET 
new_in_dc.[Final PIW] = final_forecast([new_in_dc].[In Transit Status],
[new_in_dc].[LDP],
[new_in_dc].[FGPO Mode Ship],
[new_in_dc].[FGPO Start Ship Dt],
[new_in_dc].[FGPO Prj In Wh Dt],
[new_in_dc].[Asn Mode Shp],
[new_in_dc].[Asn Prj In Wh Dt],
[new_in_dc].[FGPO Maker],
[new_in_dc].[Origin Port Delay],
[new_in_dc].[Water Delay],
[new_in_dc].[POD Delay],
[new_in_dc].[Transit Delay],
[new_in_dc].[Manual PIW],
[new_in_dc].[Delivery Date]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can (should) remove those last two commas in the list of arguments to `final_forecast`

When passing arguments by position, you only need the commas in the middle of the arguments list: if at the end they should be left off.

What happens if you try to run a query like this in your database?

```
select final_forecast(t.[In Transit Status],
t.[LDP],
t.[FGPO Mode Ship],
t.[FGPO Start Ship Dt],
t.[FGPO Prj In Wh Dt],
t.[Asn Mode Shp],
t.[Asn Prj In Wh Dt],
t.[FGPO Maker],
t.[Origin Port Delay],
t.[Water Delay],
t.[POD Delay],
t.[Transit Delay],
t.[Manual PIW],
t.[Delivery Date])
from new_in_dc t
```

Comment: In the project the code uses fields as arguments: UPDATE new_in_dc SET new_in_dc.[Final PIW] = final_forecast([new_in_dc].[In Transit Status],[new_in_dc].[LDP],[new_in_dc].[FGPO Mode Ship],[new_in_dc].[FGPO Start Ship Dt],[new_in_dc].[FGPO Prj In Wh Dt],[new_in_dc].[Asn Mode Shp],[new_in_dc].[Asn Prj In Wh Dt],[new_in_dc].[FGPO Maker],[new_in_dc].[Origin Port Delay],[new_in_dc].[Water Delay],[new_in_dc].[POD Delay],[new_in_dc].[Transit Delay],[new_in_dc].[Manual PIW],[new_in_dc].[Delivery Date]);

Comment: I'm not sure if there's still a problem here?  If Yes then please update your question to describe what it is.

Comment: OK: I am passing the arguments as fields from a table. I do not have the option to remove the last 2 arguments if the fields are null. Whatever is in the field goes in as an argument to my function. Hope I am explaining myself well. @tim

Comment: Well if they are null then the values passed will be null (which is not the same as not proving the arguments at all).  What is the actual error you're seeing when you run that?   What error are you getting, and at what point in your code?

Comment: When I run the sample row I provided in the immediate window, it gives the Compile Error: Expected:expression upon pressing enter.

Comment: Did you remove the last two commas as suggested?

Comment: Those 2 commas are for the last 2 arguments ([new_in_dc].[Manual PIW],
[new_in_dc].[Delivery Date]). They cannot be removed.

Comment: So pass in `null`/`0` instead of leaving them empty?

Comment: I tried wrapping those fields with Nz([Field],0) and got the same error.

Comment: Is this function intended to be used only in SQL or are you also calling it using VBA?  If also from VBA, it would be useful to show more of the code you use for that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove to two trailing commas and it will run:

```
a = final_forecast("In Transit",,"B",#6/23/21#,#9/20/21#,"B",#8/11/21#,0,0,27,0,0)
```

If you use the function in a query whery you may have *Null* values for some records for a required field, use *Nz* to provide a valid value, for example for the last two arguments, the date of today:

```
a:final_forecast("In Transit",Nz([FieldA],"N/A"),"B",#6/23/21#,#9/20/21#,"B",#8/11/21#,0,0,27,0,0,Nz([FieldB],Date()),Nz([FieldC],Date()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap everything in Nz([Field],0) to get the update query to get my UDF to work.

```
UPDATE new_in_dc SET new_in_dc.[Final PIW] = final_forecast([new_in_dc].[In Transit Status],nz([new_in_dc].[LDP],0),nz([new_in_dc].[FGPO Mode Ship],0),nz([new_in_dc].[FGPO Start Ship Dt],0),nz([new_in_dc].[FGPO Prj In Wh Dt],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Asn Mode Shp],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Asn Prj In Wh Dt],0),nz([new_in_dc].[FGPO Maker],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Origin Port Delay],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Water Delay],0),nz([new_in_dc].[POD Delay],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Transit Delay],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Manual PIW],0),nz([new_in_dc].[Delivery Date],0));
```